# Ajax Calls not executing - The return value from Controller is not taken

Tags: ajax, controller

The controller returns Integer 0 if there are no errors and -1 if there are exceptions to the ajax call. Below is the ajax call that I have typed in the javascript

```
$("#Form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url : "Report.do",
        type : "GET",
        cache : false,
        dataType : "application/json",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success : function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            if(data == 0){
                alert("Report has been sent");
            }else{
                alert("Report is not sent");
            }
        },
        error:function(status,xhr){
            alert("Error while generating email");
        }
        });
});
```

The Controller returns Integer properly . But the success or error block is not getting executed in the ajax call  . Not sure what is wrong. Please suggest me an idea

Comment: What happens when you debug this?  Is the AJAX call made?  What is the server's response?  If the call is made then either `success` or `error` *must* be called (unless something is *really* wrong here).  Which one is called?  What happens when you step through that function in the debugger?

Comment: Ajax call is made as the the url opens in the web page and display the output there. Why its not getting back to the ajax call . How to print the servers response in ajax call

Comment: What do you mean by, "the the url opens in the web page and display the output there"?  If the *whole page* is navigating to something then it's not using AJAX.  It's really not clear what the problem is based on your description...

Comment: Then i Can understand my jsp form is not calling the ajax call

Comment: Try data == "0" in your test. See, I put 0 in quotes.

Comment: The call was not inside document.ready function so the call was not made from jsp and its working now